# Inconsistent postgresql query performance varying from 50ms to 10s

Tags: postgresql, time-series, query-optimization

I am quite new to postgresql. The table I have here is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE public."Payload"
(
    "time" numeric NOT NULL,
    data numeric NOT NULL,
    id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('"Payload_id_seq"'::regclass),
    CONSTRAINT "Payload_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "Payload_idx"
    ON public."Payload" USING btree
    (time)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

Data was coming at 20ms interval so in a few days we got 45M rows. User will select a timerange and a resampled dataset will be returned. By resample I mean we find start id and stop id, generate a series of ids with some calculated interval then select data by these ids.

Here is the function to get the start id: getStartId(_name text, _time integer)

```
DECLARE
    myId INT;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE format('SELECT id FROM (
        (SELECT id, time FROM %I WHERE time<=$1 ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1)
        UNION ALL
        (SELECT id, time FROM %I WHERE time>$1 ORDER BY time LIMIT 1)
    ) AS startId ORDER BY time LIMIT 1;', _name, _name) into myId
    USING _time;

    RETURN myId;
END;
```

Here is the function to get the stop id: getStopId(_name text, _time integer)

```
DECLARE
    myId INT;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE format('SELECT id FROM (
        (SELECT id, time FROM %I WHERE time<=$1 ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1)
        UNION ALL
        (SELECT id, time FROM %I WHERE time>$1 ORDER BY time LIMIT 1)
    ) AS stopId ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1;', _name, _name) into myId
    USING _time;

    RETURN myId;
END;
```

Then the function to resample the data from the big table: getFilteredData(_name text, _start integer, _stop integer, _size integer)

```
DECLARE
    startId INT;
    stopId INT;
    step NUMERIC;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'SELECT getStartId($1, $2);' INTO startId USING _name, _start;
    EXECUTE 'SELECT getStopId($1, $2);' INTO stopId USING _name, _stop;

    step := (stopId-startId)/(_size-1);
    IF step<1.0 THEN
        RETURN QUERY 
        EXECUTE format('SELECT * FROM %I WHERE id IN (SELECT generate_series($1, $2)::BIGINT) ORDER BY time DESC', _name)
        USING startId, stopId;
    ELSE
        RETURN QUERY
        EXECUTE format('SELECT * FROM %I WHERE id IN (SELECT round($1*generate_series(0, $2-1)+$3)::BIGINT) ORDER BY time DESC', _name)
        USING step, _size, startId;
    END IF;
END;
```

When I do something like this:

```
SELECT epoch, data FROM getFilteredData('Payload',1483861206,1483861235,1000)
```

interesting things happen. Sometimes, especially when the range is big this kind of queries cost 4-8s up to 15s to finish. But sometimes only 20-40ms which is very acceptable.

Another thing to mention here is that if we modify getFilteredData to return only the selected ids like this:

```
SELECT round($1*generate_series(0, $2-1)+$3)::BIGINT
```

then the query finishes at about 20ms every time so I guess the problem is really in:

```
SELECT * FROM 'Payload' WHERE id IN (......)
```

I have done `Vacuum full` on this table but still doesn't help. Running `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` doesn't give much information on this command either.

Any suggestions? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Did you check the explain plan?

Comment: `IN (SELECT generate_series($1, $2)::BIGINT` looks terrible. (en the round() version looks even worse)  Why don't you use a simple range-query? [generate_series() is not known by the optimiser. It is just a function. Number of returned rows is assumed to be 1000. Always]

Comment: I agree with wildplasser `id IN (SELECT generate_series($1, $2)::BIGINT)` can simply be replace with `id between $1 and $2`- that will be a lot more efficient. Also `SELECT round($1*generate_series(0, $2-1)+$3)::BIGINT` is the best obfuscated expression I have ever seen. I have been staring at it for several minutes now and still can't understand what it's intended to do. Calling `round()` on the result of a set returning function simply does not make any sense to me

Comment: Thank you guys for the prompt replies. For example 3000 data rows I want to create a series like 1, 4, 7, 10 ..... 3000 then select them to avoid loading all these 3000 rows, from the idea in https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/how-to-sample-rows-in-sql-273x-faster.html

Comment: @Globalhawk then something like `id BETWEEN startId AND stopId AND (id - 1) % step = 0` should be enough for you. There is no need to call `generate_series()` at all.

Comment: Also, if `id` can have gaps, the [`percentile_disc()` ordered-set aggregate](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html) might be an interest of yours.

Comment: @pozs Thanks, but will ` (id - 1) % step = 0` operation actually traverse every id within the range? It turns out to be much slower if the range is big.

Comment: @Globalhawk no, the point is to not traverse them, like with `generate_series()`. `(id - 1) % step = 0` is just a mathematical formula, which is a lot faster to evaluate than `... in (select generate_series(...))`

Comment: @pozs I have done some tests lately. If there are tens of millions rows between startId and stopId `(id - 1) % step = 0` is taking seconds while `generate_series()` takes around 100ms, just like the result shown here https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/how-to-sample-rows-in-sql-273x-faster.html.